# How to get Atom editor to not close a deleted file?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm a Sublime user in the process of switching to Atom.

Atom, like Sublime, will detect when a file has changed on disk (such as when I switch git branches from the command line) and refresh any files I'm editing that have changed on disk.

However, when a previous file *disappears* (e.g., doesn't exist in the older branch I temporarily switch to), Sublime kept that file in the editor (as if it was newly edited and unsaved), whereas Atom notices that the file is deleted and will completely close the tab editing the file!

Is there a way I can stop this behavior? I want the auto-update of files that change, but I don't want the "close" of files that no longer exist on disk.

Primarily, this is so that if I temporarily switch to an old branch, do some work or compare some files, then switch back, I'm not confused by having tabs I was working on (and wish to work on again) missing. Secondarily, it's to protect me against accidentally deleting a file on the command line -- having a copy in the live editor, that I can re-save if I discover my mistake, is a nice safety feature.

Comment: Atom does not do this to me on Linux or Mac OSX since version 1.0. What environment do you have?

Comment: Mac, using Atom 1.8.0.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any options that control this. Do you know what package, specifically, is responsible for keeping an eye on changing files and what to do about it?

Comment: Seems this has been changed with https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5394. See last comments about the negative side of it, that you (and me) also experience.